# Magento cache problem

Tags: caching, magento, conflict

I have a weird problem with Magento cache.

I have an extension that have a Block output. If I change anything in the Block/* code it **is not** reflected in the front-end. If I delete anything in the Block/* it **is not** reflected at the front end. If I disable the module or delete etc/config.xml it **does** reflected at the front-end.

Cache is disabled and additionally I ran rm -fr var/cache/* before I refresh browsers page.

Please advise.

**UPDATE:**

This is Magento 1.3.2.3, so there's no System --> Tools --> Compilation menu nor shell/compiler.php. I found the following code in index.php:

```
/**
 * Error reporting
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

/**
 * Compilation includes configuration file
 */
$compilerConfig = 'includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include($compilerConfig);
}
```

but there's no includes folder at all so I think compiler is not the issue.

Also here is the code of config.xml of my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <googleanalytics>
                <rewrite>
                    <ga>Namename_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga</ga>
                </rewrite>
            </googleanalytics>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**UPDATE:**

**Look for my self-ansver for the solution (quite a dumb).**

Comment: Please check the code for the module's layout XML, from where the Block Type is set. According to your question, it seems that your Block file is not even called at all.

Comment: I added config.xml into question description. Please look above.

Comment: Rather than deleting the question, phrase your solution above in the form of an answer that someone searching for the same problem would be able to understand the problem and solve it. Post that as an answer below and then hit the checkbox to accept it as the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turned out to be quite a dumb but I agree with Joseph Mastey and maybe it will help anyone else ran into this issue.

The problem was solved by another extension overriding the same class. So either disable rival extension, edit it or modify tags.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the Magento compiler turned on? This would cause problems that behave in the way you specify.

Answer (score 1):

The `config.xml` should have the following code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namename_GoogleAnalytics>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Namename_GoogleAnalytics>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <namenamegoogleanalytics>
                <class>Namename_GoogleAnalytics_Block</class>
            </namenamegoogleanalytics>
            <googleanalytics>
                <rewrite>
                    <ga>Namename_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga</ga>
                </rewrite>
            </googleanalytics>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Also other than the "`blocks`" & "`global`" nodes, you may need to provide other nodes as required.

Hope it helps.